# Tmux - Open a new session in another terminal window without blocking the calling terminal

Tags: shell-script, tmux

I'm writing a bash script. From the script, I want to run `tmux new-session -s name`
 The tmux should open in another terminal without blocking the calling terminal's input.
On the main terminal window there are lots of options to choose from, and it waits for the users input. The tmux session would have multiple windows that displays output depending on the selection made by the user. So the main terminal window should not be blocked.

What i tried

```
tmux new-session -s name &   <--- Completely messes up the tmux session
nohup tmux new-session -s name &    <---- Doesn't work too
```

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can open an entirely new terminal with something like "xterm -e 'tmux new'".